# Marklogic Java API Semantic Triple Search

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

i inserted json document into Server and using the document created the triples. With the triples using SPARQL process and insert new triples as output in a collection. Now i want to search in triples collection. 
Like Document search in Java Client api(google like), searching is possible in triples?
If not please suggest any solution for above scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple powerful options at your disposal here.  I'll highlight two:

- [Search your original JSON documents Using String Query Definition](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_80640) (google like)
- Use [SPARQLQueryManager](http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/semantics/SPARQLQueryManager.html) to run SPARQL queries [only on documents which match](http://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/semantics/SPARQLQueryDefinition.html#setConstrainingQueryDefinition(com.marklogic.client.query.QueryDefinition)) your google-like string query

I suggest you do either on a collection holding your original JSON documents, because you know exactly what's in each one and how your string queries will match.  If you instead query the collection containing triples you created with SPARQL, those are [managed triples](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/copyright/glossary#id_84269) which means many triples are in one document so your constraining queries won't narrow as precisely.

If you really want to search your managed triples you could use this more precise but less efficient approach:

- [Use built-in functions in a SPARQL Query](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/semantics/semantic-searches#id_46386) with cts:contains

Answer (score 0):

There is always the MarkLogic Query Console (http://localhost:8000/qconsole/).  Create a new tab, choose the Query type as SPARQL Query (or Update), and choose the Content Source containing the triples.

Place the SPARQL query in the body of the Query console and the query will be executed across all triples in the selected Content Source/